# Would multiple images with the same alt text as the page name be keyword stuffing?

Tags: google, web-development, web-crawlers

In a page I have three or four images that have same alt tag as of my page name.  Could Google consider that to be keyword and penalize my site?

Is it good practice to include page name in alt tag?

- Page name - Lobo
- for image 1 - alt tag (Lobo)
- for image 2 - alt tag (Lobo)

Comment: Think of your impaired users... if it sucks for them, it sucks for search engines. Unless they are the same image then there should never be duplicate alt tags. Also different respective and angles of should be described. Alt tag was designed for impaired users, not search engines, Google employees forget this.

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to get actively "penalized" for such a trivial offence (I'm assuming you're not stuffing the ALT attribute with *reams* of text).

Incorrectly assigned ALT text is a common faux pas.

However, this isn't going to do you any favours either and your site is going to be less "accessible" as a result.

> Is it good practice to include page name in alt tag?

"Good practice" doesn't really enter into it. (But, no, it's not "good practice".)

The ALT text is meant to be *alternative* text for the image - when the image cannot be used (for whatever reason). Does the "page name" relate directly to the image content (probably not)?

If you are unable to supply meaningful ALT text, then it is probably best to provide no ALT text at all. ie. an empty ALT attribute. (At least then you won't frustrate your users quite so much.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that duplicate alt text on images is keyword stuffing. In fact, it could be useful to Google's crawler if done right. Let's say you have 10 different images, all of cute cats. And let's say that you made the alt text alt="cute cat". This could be very helpful to Google as it may index all 10 of your images in its image search, and those images might be displayed when someone is searching for cute cats.

You don't need to have your alt text unique. What matters most is that the alt text most accurately describes your image in the best way that you can.

Answer (score 0):

If we use the same alt text for all images, Google will most likely only notice one image because they are not unique. Which might be fine depending on the images. The image alt text is one of the big factors in Google's Image Search so the closer you can get to what customers would search for, the better.